# Replace fragment with another fragment without new activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my fragment, I am trying to change the fragment from in the fragment. I know I could create a new activity with the new fragment, then just create and intent and go that route. But I have an activity that has some content on it that I would really like to only update in one spot. Can anyone tell me how I would go about changing the fragment to another fragment while still using the activity I originally created?

```
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inst_fragment, container, false);
    furnTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.furn_textview);
    archTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.arch_textview);

    furnTextView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()){
                openCatalog("furn");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    archTextView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()){
                openCatalog("arch");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return view;
```

Comment: is your fragment declared in your xml?

Comment: No the fragment is dynamically loaded. From the main activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way you can "add" another `Fragment` to your `Activity` without creating one is using `replace()` function. This is the way probably you are adding your first `Fragment` in your `FragmentActivity` :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        MyFirstFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

}

And using `replace` in `FragmentTransaction` you can replace `MyFirstFragment` with another one :

```
MyNewFragment newFragment = new MyNewFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

That's all. Hope it helps! : )

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will replace your current fragment and on back your old fragment will be restored.

```
NewFragment fragment = NewFragment.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack("BACKSTACK");
ft.replace(R.id.home_list, fragment);
ft.commit(
```

Comment: Yes you have access to FragmentManager from fragment by function getSupportFragmentManager or getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(). NewFragment is your second Fragment